# cannot find module in another directory

Tags: python

I have the project structure:

```
/hdfs-archiver
   /logs
   /qe
      __init__.py
      /tests
         __init__.py
         archiver.py
      /utils
         __init__.py
         HdfsConnector.py
```

I am trying to run `archiver.py` but I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "qe/tests/HdfsArchiver.py", line 8, in <module>
    from qe.utils import HdfsConnector
ImportError: No module named qe.utils
```

I read around and it seemed like most people that come across this issue fixed it with `__init__.py`

when I `pwd`:

```
$ pwd
/Users/bli1/Development/QE/idea/hdfs-archiver
```

my `PYTHONPATH` in `.bashrc`

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Users/bli1/Development/QE/idea/hdfs-archiver
```

I also tried having my `PYTHONPATH` as

```
/Users/bli1/Development/QE/idea/hdfs-archiver/qe
```

Comment: @hiroprotagonist yes it is. Still I get the same error

Comment: Where are you running the file from? So, are you typing `python ~/Development/QE/idea/hdfs-archiver/qe/tests/archiver.py` or are you typing `python archiver.py`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I am currently in the `qe` directory and I am running `python tests/archiver.py`. Ideally I could like to be able to run `archiver.py` from any directory and still have it work so long as I provide the correct path to `archiver.py`

Comment: would it make any difference if you had `__init__.py` in the `hdfs-archiver` directory (root).

Comment: The `qe` module is not in your PYTHONPATH variable, which is why the import is not working. You can get around this, by doing a relative import.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I added `qe` at the very end of my `PYTHONPATH` but still  same error =[

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to import HdfsConnector as a function or class. Include the HdfsConnector module as part of your absolute import:

```
from qe.utils.HdfsConnector import my_function
```

You can also import the module:

```
import qe.utils.HdfsConnector
# or
import qe.utils.HdfsConnector as HdfsConnector
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you could try a relative import such as

```
from ..utils import HdfsConnector
```

You'd also need to run the script as a module and not as a simple python script due to the __name__ being different. This wouldn't require you to modify the path.
You can find more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py).